# Lua OOP: Problems with tables

Tags: oop, lua

There some problems with my OOP.
I have parent with clear table and child with same table.
When i'm trying to add object to table of child, object adds to parent's table.

Simple example:

```
Account = {}
Account.__index = Account
Account.kit = {}

function Account.create(balance)
   local acnt = {}             -- our new object
   setmetatable(acnt,Account)  -- make Account handle lookup
   acnt.balance = balance      -- initialize our object
   return acnt
end

function Account:withdraw(amount)
   self.balance = self.balance - amount
end

-- create and use an Account
acc = Account.create(1000)
acc:withdraw(100)


table.insert(acc.kit, "1")

print(#Account.kit)
print(#acc.kit)
```

Result is 1 and 1.
But must be 0 and 1.

How i can isolate child table from parent?

Comment: You should create additional `kit` inside an object during object initialization: `acnt.kit = setmetatable({}, {__index = Account.kit})`

Comment: Thanks, it's works, but in my object too much tables and i can't do it for every one. Something like this not working:
 for i, v in ipairs(Account) do
        if v == {} then
     acnt.v = setmetatable({}, {__index = Account.v})
        end
   end

Comment: `for k, v in pairs(Account) do if type(v)=='table' and v~=Account then acnt[k] = setmetatable({}, {__index = v}) end end`

Comment: Thanks! This works fine.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Don't use comments for answers.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Feel free to write good/complete/exhaustive answer based on my comments and earn some rep points  ;-)  I'm too lazy to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

In Lua using `acc.kit` where `acc` is a table with the metatable `Account` will first search the key `kit` from the table `acc` and then from table `Account`.

In your code `acc` does not have anything with key `kit`, so the `Account.kit` will be accessed.

You can solve this simply by defining the kit table for the acc on creation

```
Account = {}
Account.__index = Account
Account.kit = {} -- You can now remove this if you do not use it - I preserved it to make the test prints to still work.

function Account.create(balance)
   local acnt = {}             -- our new object
   setmetatable(acnt,Account)  -- make Account handle lookup
   acnt.balance = balance      -- initialize our object
   acnt.kit = {}               -- define kit to be a subtable
   return acnt
end
```

Example:
https://repl.it/B6P1

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using closures to implement OOP:

```
local Animal = {}

function Animal.new(name)

  local self = {}
  self.name = name

  function self.PrintName()
    print("My name is " .. self.name)
  end

  return self

end

--now a class dog that will inherit from animal
local Dog = {}

function Dog.new(name)

  -- to inherit from Animal, we create an instance of it
  local self = Animal.new(name)

  function self.Bark()
    print(self.name .. " barked!")
  end

  return self

end


local fred = Dog.new("Fred")
fred.Bark()
fred.PrintName()
```

output:

Fred barked!

My name is Fred